# Product Configuration based on user selection of features and other requirements

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pattern-recognition

Is this a scenario that would work well for a ML/Pattern Recognition Model or would it be easier/faster to just filter from a large DB.

I am looking to create a system that will allow users to identify the appropriate product by specifying certain constraints and preferred features.

There are millions of possible product configurations. Lets pretend it's boxes.

Product Options:

- Size (From 1mm up to 1m) in 1mm increments
- Color: choice of 10 colors
- Material: choice of 3, wood,metal, plastic

Constraints:

- Wood is only available in centimeter units
- Red is only available in 500 mm and greater
- Wood is the preferred material
- Blue is the preferred color

So, we have 30,000 (1000*10*3) possible options.
Of those, many are not viable such as 533 mm-Red-Wood

but these configurations similar to the request are possible.

- 533 mm-Red-Plastic
- 530 mm-Red-Wood
- 540 mm-Red-Wood

Notes:
Our current Rules and code based tool can take anywhere from 0.5 to 2 mins to identify the preferred configuration.
We can generate a list of all possible configs and whether they are valid or not.
We estimate 30,000,000 possible configs
It takes around 0.5 seconds to validate a config so with enough computing power we expect we could do 30M in a few days.